# How to fix the error `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch

My problem is when I running FC network the code works well in both CPU and GPU. But when it comes to CNN, I can only train it on CPU. It raises an error when I try to train it on GPU.

Like that:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I find the error raised when the code goes to loss.backword. The error happened when I use the first column instead of the second.

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0")

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if opt.cuda else "cpu")
```

My environment is Python 3.6.9, Windows 10, Torch 1.2.0, Cuda 9.2.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured out this.

This error occurs just because one of my variables is not loaded in cuda.

When I add this output = `Variable(netD(real_cpu),requires_grad=True)` the problem solved.